# Jquery Not Working on New Site

Tags: jquery

When previewing the site, everything functions correctly, however when live the scrollbar within the popups for Services and Works are not active at all. www.truemotionworks.com

Please let me know if I can provide any additional helpful information! Thanks

html code starts with:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>True Motion Works Property Visualizations and Marketing</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<link href="jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

jquery.mCustomScrollbar is as follows:

```
/* malihu custom scrollbar plugin - http://manos.malihu.gr */
(function ($) {
$.fn.mCustomScrollbar = function (scrollType,animSpeed,easeType,bottomSpace,draggerDimType,mouseWheelSupport,scrollBtnsSupport,scrollBtnsSpeed){
var id = $(this).attr("id");
var $customScrollBox=$("#"+id+" .customScrollBox");
var $customScrollBox_container=$("#"+id+" .customScrollBox .container");
var $customScrollBox_content=$("#"+id+" .customScrollBox .content");
var $dragger_container=$("#"+id+" .dragger_container");
var $dragger=$("#"+id+" .dragger");
var $scrollUpBtn=$("#"+id+" .scrollUpBtn");
var $scrollDownBtn=$("#"+id+" .scrollDownBtn");
var $customScrollBox_horWrapper=$("#"+id+" .customScrollBox .horWrapper");

//get & store minimum dragger height & width (defined in css)
if(!$customScrollBox.data("minDraggerHeight")){
    $customScrollBox.data("minDraggerHeight",$dragger.height());
}
if(!$customScrollBox.data("minDraggerWidth")){
    $customScrollBox.data("minDraggerWidth",$dragger.width());
}

//get & store original content height & width
if(!$customScrollBox.data("contentHeight")){
    $customScrollBox.data("contentHeight",$customScrollBox_container.height());
}
if(!$customScrollBox.data("contentWidth")){
    $customScrollBox.data("contentWidth",$customScrollBox_container.width());
}

CustomScroller();

function CustomScroller(reloadType){
    //horizontal scrolling ------------------------------
    if(scrollType=="horizontal"){
        var visibleWidth=$customScrollBox.width();
        //set content width automatically
        $customScrollBox_horWrapper.css("width",999999); //set a rediculously high width value ;)
        $customScrollBox.data("totalContent",$customScrollBox_container.width()); //get inline div width
        $customScrollBox_horWrapper.css("width",$customScrollBox.data("totalContent")); //set back the proper content width value

        if($customScrollBox_container.width()>visibleWidth){ //enable scrollbar if content is long
            $dragger.css("display","block");
            if(reloadType!="resize" && $customScrollBox_container.width()!=$customScrollBox.data("contentWidth")){
                $dragger.css("left",0);
                $customScrollBox_container.css("left",0);
                $customScrollBox.data("contentWidth",$customScrollBox_container.width());
            }
            $dragger_container.css("display","block");
            $scrollDownBtn.css("display","inline-block");
            $scrollUpBtn.css("display","inline-block");
            var totalContent=$customScrollBox_content.width();
            var minDraggerWidth=$customScrollBox.data("minDraggerWidth");
            var draggerContainerWidth=$dragger_container.width();

            function AdjustDraggerWidth(){
                if(draggerDimType=="auto"){
                    var adjDraggerWidth=Math.round(totalContent-((totalContent-visibleWidth)*1.3)); //adjust dragger width analogous to content
                    if(adjDraggerWidth<=minDraggerWidth){ //minimum dragger width
                        $dragger.css("width",minDraggerWidth+"px");
                    } else if(adjDraggerWidth>=draggerContainerWidth){
                        $dragger.css("width",draggerContainerWidth-10+"px");
                    } else {
                        $dragger.css("width",adjDraggerWidth+"px");
                    }
                }
            }
            AdjustDraggerWidth();

            var targX=0;
            var draggerWidth=$dragger.width();
            $dragger.draggable({ 
                axis: "x", 
                containment: "parent", 
                drag: function(event, ui) {
                    ScrollX();
                }, 
                stop: function(event, ui) {
                    DraggerRelease();
                }
            });

            $dragger_container.click(function(e) {
                var $this=$(this);
                var mouseCoord=(e.pageX - $this.offset().left);
                if(mouseCoord<$dragger.position().left || mouseCoord>($dragger.position().left+$dragger.width())){
                    var targetPos=mouseCoord+$dragger.width();
                    if(targetPos<$dragger_container.width()){
                        $dragger.css("left",mouseCoord);
                        ScrollX();
                    } else {
                        $dragger.css("left",$dragger_container.width()-$dragger.width());
                        ScrollX();
                    }
                }
            });

            //mousewheel
            $(function($) {
                if(mouseWheelSupport=="yes"){
                    $customScrollBox.unbind("mousewheel");
                    $customScrollBox.bind("mousewheel", function(event, delta) {
                        var vel = Math.abs(delta*10);
                        $dragger.css("left", $dragger.position().left-(delta*vel));
                        ScrollX();
                        if($dragger.position().left<0){
                            $dragger.css("left", 0);
                            $customScrollBox_container.stop();
                            ScrollX();
                        }
                        if($dragger.position().left>$dragger_container.width()-$dragger.width()){
                            $dragger.css("left", $dragger_container.width()-$dragger.width());
                            $customScrollBox_container.stop();
                            ScrollX();
                        }
                        return false;
                    });
                }
            });

            //scroll buttons
            if(scrollBtnsSupport=="yes"){
                $scrollDownBtn.mouseup(function(){
                    BtnsScrollXStop();
                }).mousedown(function(){
                    BtnsScrollX("down");
                }).mouseout(function(){
                    BtnsScrollXStop();
                });

                $scrollUpBtn.mouseup(function(){
                    BtnsScrollXStop();
                }).mousedown(function(){
                    BtnsScrollX("up");
                }).mouseout(function(){
                    BtnsScrollXStop();
                });

                $scrollDownBtn.click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
                $scrollUpBtn.click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                });

                btnsScrollTimerX=0;

                function BtnsScrollX(dir){
                    if(dir=="down"){
                        var btnsScrollTo=$dragger_container.width()-$dragger.width();
                        var scrollSpeed=Math.abs($dragger.position().left-btnsScrollTo)*(100/scrollBtnsSpeed);
                        $dragger.stop().animate({left: btnsScrollTo}, scrollSpeed,"linear");
                    } else {
                        var btnsScrollTo=0;
                        var scrollSpeed=Math.abs($dragger.position().left-btnsScrollTo)*(100/scrollBtnsSpeed);
                        $dragger.stop().animate({left: -btnsScrollTo}, scrollSpeed,"linear");
                    }
                    clearInterval(btnsScrollTimerX);
                    btnsScrollTimerX = setInterval( ScrollX, 20);
                }

                function BtnsScrollXStop(){
                    clearInterval(btnsScrollTimerX);
                    $dragger.stop();
                }
            }

            //scroll
            var scrollAmount=(totalContent-visibleWidth)/(draggerContainerWidth-draggerWidth);
            function ScrollX(){
                var draggerX=$dragger.position().left;
                var targX=-draggerX*scrollAmount;
                var thePos=$customScrollBox_container.position().left-targX;
                $customScrollBox_container.stop().animate({left: "-="+thePos}, animSpeed, easeType);
            }
        } else { //disable scrollbar if content is short
            $dragger.css("left",0).css("display","none"); //reset content scroll
            $customScrollBox_container.css("left",0);
            $dragger_container.css("display","none");
            $scrollDownBtn.css("display","none");
            $scrollUpBtn.css("display","none");
        }
    //vertical scrolling ------------------------------
    } else {
        var visibleHeight=$customScrollBox.height();
        if($customScrollBox_container.height()>visibleHeight){ //enable scrollbar if content is long
            $dragger.css("display","block");
            if(reloadType!="resize" && $customScrollBox_container.height()!=$customScrollBox.data("contentHeight")){
                $dragger.css("top",0);
                $customScrollBox_container.css("top",0);
                $customScrollBox.data("contentHeight",$customScrollBox_container.height());
            }
            $dragger_container.css("display","block");
            $scrollDownBtn.css("display","inline-block");
            $scrollUpBtn.css("display","inline-block");
            var totalContent=$customScrollBox_content.height();
            var minDraggerHeight=$customScrollBox.data("minDraggerHeight");
            var draggerContainerHeight=$dragger_container.height();

            function AdjustDraggerHeight(){
                if(draggerDimType=="auto"){
                    var adjDraggerHeight=Math.round(totalContent-((totalContent-visibleHeight)*1.3)); //adjust dragger height analogous to content
                    if(adjDraggerHeight<=minDraggerHeight){ //minimum dragger height
                        $dragger.css("height",minDraggerHeight+"px").css("line-height",minDraggerHeight+"px");
                    } else if(adjDraggerHeight>=draggerContainerHeight){
                        $dragger.css("height",draggerContainerHeight-10+"px").css("line-height",draggerContainerHeight-10+"px");
                    } else {
                        $dragger.css("height",adjDraggerHeight+"px").css("line-height",adjDraggerHeight+"px");
                    }
                }
            }
            AdjustDraggerHeight();

            var targY=0;
            var draggerHeight=$dragger.height();
            $dragger.draggable({ 
                axis: "y", 
                containment: "parent", 
                drag: function(event, ui) {
                    Scroll();
                }, 
                stop: function(event, ui) {
                    DraggerRelease();
                }
            });

            $dragger_container.click(function(e) {
                var $this=$(this);
                var mouseCoord=(e.pageY - $this.offset().top);
                if(mouseCoord<$dragger.position().top || mouseCoord>($dragger.position().top+$dragger.height())){
                    var targetPos=mouseCoord+$dragger.height();
                    if(targetPos<$dragger_container.height()){
                        $dragger.css("top",mouseCoord);
                        Scroll();
                    } else {
                        $dragger.css("top",$dragger_container.height()-$dragger.height());
                        Scroll();
                    }
                }
            });

            //mousewheel
            $(function($) {
                if(mouseWheelSupport=="yes"){
                    $customScrollBox.unbind("mousewheel");
                    $customScrollBox.bind("mousewheel", function(event, delta) {
                        var vel = Math.abs(delta*10);
                        $dragger.css("top", $dragger.position().top-(delta*vel));
                        Scroll();
                        if($dragger.position().top<0){
                            $dragger.css("top", 0);
                            $customScrollBox_container.stop();
                            Scroll();
                        }
                        if($dragger.position().top>$dragger_container.height()-$dragger.height()){
                            $dragger.css("top", $dragger_container.height()-$dragger.height());
                            $customScrollBox_container.stop();
                            Scroll();
                        }
                        return false;
                    });
                }
            });

            //scroll buttons
            if(scrollBtnsSupport=="yes"){
                $scrollDownBtn.mouseup(function(){
                    BtnsScrollStop();
                }).mousedown(function(){
                    BtnsScroll("down");
                }).mouseout(function(){
                    BtnsScrollStop();
                });

                $scrollUpBtn.mouseup(function(){
                    BtnsScrollStop();
                }).mousedown(function(){
                    BtnsScroll("up");
                }).mouseout(function(){
                    BtnsScrollStop();
                });

                $scrollDownBtn.click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
                $scrollUpBtn.click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                });

                btnsScrollTimer=0;

                function BtnsScroll(dir){
                    if(dir=="down"){
                        var btnsScrollTo=$dragger_container.height()-$dragger.height();
                        var scrollSpeed=Math.abs($dragger.position().top-btnsScrollTo)*(100/scrollBtnsSpeed);
                        $dragger.stop().animate({top: btnsScrollTo}, scrollSpeed,"linear");
                    } else {
                        var btnsScrollTo=0;
                        var scrollSpeed=Math.abs($dragger.position().top-btnsScrollTo)*(100/scrollBtnsSpeed);
                        $dragger.stop().animate({top: -btnsScrollTo}, scrollSpeed,"linear");
                    }
                    clearInterval(btnsScrollTimer);
                    btnsScrollTimer = setInterval( Scroll, 20);
                }

                function BtnsScrollStop(){
                    clearInterval(btnsScrollTimer);
                    $dragger.stop();
                }
            }

            //scroll
            if(bottomSpace<1){
                bottomSpace=1; //minimum bottomSpace value is 1
            }
            var scrollAmount=(totalContent-(visibleHeight/bottomSpace))/(draggerContainerHeight-draggerHeight);
            function Scroll(){
                var draggerY=$dragger.position().top;
                var targY=-draggerY*scrollAmount;
                var thePos=$customScrollBox_container.position().top-targY;
                $customScrollBox_container.stop().animate({top: "-="+thePos}, animSpeed, easeType);
            }
        } else { //disable scrollbar if content is short
            $dragger.css("top",0).css("display","none"); //reset content scroll
            $customScrollBox_container.css("top",0);
            $dragger_container.css("display","none");
            $scrollDownBtn.css("display","none");
            $scrollUpBtn.css("display","none");
        }
    }

    $dragger.mouseup(function(){
        DraggerRelease();
    }).mousedown(function(){
        DraggerPress();
    });

    function DraggerPress(){
        $dragger.addClass("dragger_pressed");
    }

    function DraggerRelease(){
        $dragger.removeClass("dragger_pressed");
    }
}

$(window).resize(function() {
    if(scrollType=="horizontal"){
        if($dragger.position().left>$dragger_container.width()-$dragger.width()){
            $dragger.css("left", $dragger_container.width()-$dragger.width());
        }
    } else {
        if($dragger.position().top>$dragger_container.height()-$dragger.height()){
            $dragger.css("top", $dragger_container.height()-$dragger.height());
        }
    }
    CustomScroller("resize");
});
};  
})(jQuery);
/* body fadeIn effect */
$('body').hide().fadeIn(2500);
/* Simple script to cache images */
$(window).load(function() {
        var imageArray = ['images/gallery/2.jpg', 'images/gallery/3.jpg', 'images/gallery/4.jpg', 'images/gallery/5.jpg', 'images/gallery/6.jpg'];
        var hidden = $('body').append('<div id="img-cache" style="display:none/>').children('#img-cache');
        $.each(imageArray, function (i, val) {
          $('<img/>').attr('src', val).appendTo(hidden);
        });
});
```

Comment: "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must **describe the specific problem** — and **include valid code** to reproduce it — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance."

Comment: the first time it is referenced it is:    <link href="jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />     does this mean it is using it and not loading? what is the fix?

Comment: The css has nothing to do with functionalities, it could be at the end with no problem, JS files are the ones that need to be ordered. Look in the console, you've got some errors to deal with. Hope this helps.

Comment: Is `jquery.mCustomScrollbar` a CSS or JS file?  You include it as a CSS file in the head, but the code you show below shows JS... so which is it?

Comment: Looking into his code, there is a jquery.mCustomScrollbar.js file but it is loaded quite late, not clear which JS calls to this plugin can be done. That would be my recommendation, load it as soon as possible (after jquery, of course), then investiguate what's causing errors in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That plugin you're using appears to require jQuery 1.9.1 on its github repo, whereas you're using version 1.4 -- would updating the jQuery and jQuery UI be of any help to you?

EDIT2:

The following CSS is set on the box:

```
#popupAbout .customScrollBox {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Removing the `overflow: hidden;` makes the scrolling work.

Comment: The pop ups come up for me, no scrolling ability. It does seem that the jquery.mcustomscrollbar.css is CSS given the .css, I can look at the versions to see if anything there helps.

Comment: See my last edit - is that helpful?

Comment: I see what you mean. I can use the default scrollbar. I think that will probably work for me. I will try to implement it later and take out the problematic custom scrollbar so it's not in the way. I will let you know when it's operating smoothly, thanks!